# Getting SUM based on quantity in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this tables

**ORDERS**

- orders_id
- order_article_id
- order_invoice_id
- order_customer_id
- order_qty

**ARTICLES**

- articles_id
- article_name
- article_qty
- article_price
- article_amount

**CUSTOMERS**

- customers_id
- customer_name
- customer_position
- customer_office

And SQL Join Table

```
$sql="SELECT customer_name, article_name, orders_id FROM orders  
            LEFT JOIN articles ON order_article_id = articles_id 
            LEFT JOIN customers  on order_customer_id = customers_id";
```

From this query I need to get AMOUNT.
Amount is example

**USER: MICHAEL**

**AMOUNT: ORDER ID = order_article_id   + order_qty;**

Is it possible to do that in MySQL or i need some addition PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in MySQL, using a GROUP BY query and a SUM() aggregate function:

```
SELECT
  c.customer_name,
  SUM(a.article_price*a.article_quantity) AS amount
FROM
  orders o LEFT JOIN articles a
  ON o.order_article_id = a.articles_id 
  LEFT JOIN customers c
  ON o.order_customer_id = c.customers_id
GROUP BY
  c.customers_id,
  c.customer_name
```

you might want to obtain the AMOUNT per order, then you need to group by also for the order_id:

```
GROUP BY
  o.orders_id,
  c.customers_id,
  c.customer_name
```

Comment: Nice what to query in foreach?

Comment: my query returns two columns, `customer_name` and the sum renamed to `amount`

Comment: Can you please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963649/getting-sum-and-result-in-several-join-tables