# Getting SUM and result in several JOIN tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this tables

**ORDERS**

- orders_id
- order_article_id
- order_invoice_id
- order_customer_id
- order_qty

**ARTICLES**

- articles_id
- article_name
- article_qty
- article_price
- article_amount

**CUSTOMERS**

- customers_id
- customer_name
- customer_position
- customer_office

**INVOICES**

- invoices_id
- date
- invoice_customer_id

And SQL Join Table

```
   $sql="SELECT customer_name, article_name, orders_id, article_price, order_qty, invoices_id FROM orders  LEFT JOIN articles ON order_article_id = articles_id
            LEFT JOIN invoices ON order_invoice_id = invoices_id 
            LEFT JOIN customers  on order_customer_id = customers_id";
```

From this query I need to get is this result example

- **INVOICE_ID**
- **CUSTOMER_NAME**
- **AMOUNT = order_qty * article_price** for that invoice

Is it possible to do that in MySQL or i need some addition PHP code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an aggregation query for this:

```
SELECT c.customer_name, i.invoices_id,
       sum(order_qty * a.article_price) as amount
FROM orders o LEFT JOIN
     articles a
     ON o.order_article_id = a.articles_id LEFT JOIN
     invoices i
     ON o.order_invoice_id = i.invoices_id LEFT JOIN
     customers c
     on o.order_customer_id = c.customers_id
GROUP BY c.customer_name, i.invoice_id;
```

Note that I've added table aliases to better specify where the columns come from.  This makes the query easier to understand.

Comment: and what result i have here in php?

Comment: sum(order_qty * a.article_price) as amount, maybe?